# D3 Chart breaks without top margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have the following D3 chart I'm building. (I'm new to D3). I'm trying to remove the top margin from the chart but it breaks the whole thing? I think I've got a bit muddled with my heights widths and margins, but after numerous attempts at trying and fix it, I just keep making it worse. How can I get rid of the top margin without breaking the whole chart?

```js
$(function(){

    initChart();

});

function initChart() {
  
 var lineDataActual = [{
  'x': 0,
  'y': 200
 }, {
  'x': 10,
  'y': 50
 }, {
  'x': 20,
  'y': 180
 }, {
  'x': 30,
  'y': 60
 }, {
  'x': 40,
  'y': 120
 }, {
  'x': 50,
  'y': 30
 }];

 var svg = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  width = 400,
  height = 300,
  margins = {
   top: 80,
   right: 50,
   bottom: 80,
   left: 80
  },
  xMin = d3.min(lineDataActual, function (d) {   
   return d.x;
  }),
  xMax = d3.max(lineDataActual, function (d) {   
   return d.x;
  }),
  yMin = d3.min(lineDataActual, function (d) {   
   return d.y;
  }),
  yMax = d3.max(lineDataActual, function (d) {   
   return d.y;
  }),

    xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([margins.left, width - margins.right]).domain([

  xMin,xMax
    ]),

 yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([height - margins.top, margins.bottom]).domain([
 
  yMin,yMax  
 ]),

 xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSubdivide(true),
 
 yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSubdivide(true);
  
 function make_x_axis() {        
  return d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xRange)
    .orient("bottom")
   .tickSubdivide(true)
 }
 
 function make_y_axis() {        
  return d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(yRange)
   .orient("left")
   .tickSubdivide(true)
 }
 
 
 svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margins.top) + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize((-height) + (margins.top + margins.bottom), 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    svg.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margins.left) + ",0)")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize((-width) + (margins.right + margins.left), 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

 svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - (margins.bottom)) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margins.left) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);
  
  

 var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
   return xRange(d.x);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
   return yRange(d.y);
  })
    .interpolate('basis');
  

 var lineDataIdeal = [{
  'x': xMin,
  'y': yMax
 }, {
  'x': xMax,
  'y': yMin 
 }];


 svg.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineDataIdeal))
  .attr("class", "ideal");
 
 svg.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineDataActual))
  .attr("class", "actual");
  
 svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "x label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", height -6)
  .text("Days");
  
 svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "y label")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text("Hours remaining");
  


}
```

```css
.chart { 
 font-family: 'Arial';
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #000;
}
.chart > .axis path,
.chart > .axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #eee;
 stroke-width:2;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.chart > .axis .tick line { 
 fill: none;
 stroke: #999;
 stroke-width:2;
}
.chart > path.ideal {
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
.chart > path.actual {
  stroke: #91E500;
  stroke-width:2;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  fill: none;
  /*fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
}
.chart > .grid .tick {
    stroke: #eee;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500" class="chart"></svg>
```

Here is a codepen as well:

http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/mtcuo

Comment: Thanks @codeVeritas. I tried that just now and it doesn't seem to work? Do you have a working example.

Comment: the code looks fine in the preview actually...

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the graph renders fine. Its just the huge gap at the top. If I try to remove the gap the graph breaks.

Comment: Have you been changing the values in the margin variable or completely removing the margin variable?

Comment: Change margin.bottom to 0 to shift the chart upward on the canvas.  I'm not 100% sure why this works.  I think it has something to do with in D3 the origin is at top left, not bottom left

Comment: @Maggie thank you for the response, it works perfectly . If you would like to post this as the answer I will happily accept it so you get the recognition. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change margin.bottom to 0 to shift the chart upward on the canvas. I'm not 100% sure why this works. I think it has something to do with in D3 the origin is at top left, not bottom left